# Python local variable in function return none

Tags: python

```
from collections import deque

def solution(rectangle, characterX, characterY, itemX, itemY):
    answer = 0
    mx=[-1,1,0,0]
    my=[0,0,1,-1]
    def bfs(x,y,move,visited): 
        if x== itemX and y==itemY:
            print(move)
            return move
        q=deque()
        q.append((x,y))
        while q:
            x,y = q.popleft()
            visited.append((x,y))
            for i in range(4):
                dx=x+mx[i]
                dy=y+my[i]
                if 0<=dx and 0<=dy:
                    if (dx,dy) not in visited:
                        for lx,ly,rx,ry in rectangle:
                            if lx<=dx<=rx and dy==ry:
                                pass
                            else:
                                continue
                                
                            visited.append((dx,dy))
                            bfs(dx,dy,move+1,visited)
                            visited.pop()

    print(bfs(characterX,characterY,0,[]))
       
    return answer
```

I returned 'move' but it returns none. I printed move to check if it is non type bue it is not none. Why doed this function return none?

Comment: The `bfs()` function returns `move` only if x == itemX and y==itemY.  Otherwise it does not return anything (and therefore returns `None` by default).

Comment: Also it appears that your outer function (`solution`) will only ever return `0`, no matter what happens.